# Vetor não imprime completamente - Python, OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Python usando OpenCV, estou rodando no Google Colab.
Quero guardar o vetor dos markers de uma imagem de um método de segmentação, mas sempre que imprimo o vetor, ele aparece resumido. Ja tentei converte-lo para String, mas ele continua resumido. Como faço para imprimi-lo por completo?

Metodo que encontra os Markers:

```
def markers():
  img = cv2.imread(imgNome)
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

 # noise removal
  kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
  opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)

  # sure background area
  sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)

  # Finding sure foreground area
  dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)
  ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.7*dist_transform.max(),255,0)

  # Finding unknown region
  sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
  unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

  # Marker labelling
  ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

  # Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
  markers = markers+1

  # Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
  markers[unknown==255] = 0

  markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)
  #img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]
  markersSTR = str(markers)
  return markersSTR
```

O jeito que o vetor esta sendo impresso:

```
 [[-1 -1 -1 ... -1 -1 -1]

 [-1  1  1 ...  1  1 -1]

 [-1  1  1 ...  1  1 -1]

 ...

 [-1  1  1 ...  2  2 -1]

 [-1  1  1 ...  2  2 -1]

 [-1 -1 -1 ... -1 -1 -1]]
```

Comment: A IDE está resumindo o vetor por ser muito grande, muitas IDEs, como o PyCharm, possuem um visualizador de vetores e dataframes. Veja [esta](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html) página de ajuda para verificar como visualizar no Pycharm. Porém, eu, pessoalmente, prefiro utilizar o [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), que possui uma interface de usuário em que você pode ver o canal de cores e cada posição de pixel com o mouse. Não sendo possível com o `imshow` do OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) no inicio do seu script:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```